# Is it possible to use Excel/Access to consume a SOAP based web service using WS-Security?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vba, soap, ws-security

The extent of my ability is in vba and asp.

I'm interested in consuming a SOAP web service from Excel or Access, mostly because it's easier for me.  I've also got the wsdls for the web service which is using ws-security.

Is this even possible?  From what I've read, .net is my logical option, but there's obviously a gap in my skill.  Is there a library, tool, or helpful guide that might help?

Thanks, B

Answer (score 0):

I think that will be difficult with VBA.

If you can limit the functionality to Office 2003+, you can use the Visual Studio Tools for the Office Runtime (VSTOR) to develop an add-in with managed .NET code, which I expect will be a much easier route.

There is a tool that is installed with Visual Studio called wsdl.exe, which can be used to generate the appropriate classes from your wsdl.

As to the specifics of ws-security, I'm not much help.

Comment: If you use WCF in your managed .NET addin you should be able to configure it for ws-security